# dbcp2 cannot load JDBC driver class

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, driver, classpath, visibility

Problem: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver'.
There are used: import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
mariaDb, maven, tomEE, javaEE.
The problem is gotten when method getConnection() of the following class is invoked.
Problem should be solved without setting db driver to tomEE classpath

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

public class MariaDbConnector {
private static BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();

static {
    ds.setDriverClassName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/hotel2?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8");
    ds.setUsername("root");
    ds.setPassword("secret");
    ds.setMinIdle(5);
    ds.setMaxIdle(10);
    ds.setMaxOpenPreparedStatements(100);
}

public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return ds.getConnection();
}

private MariaDbConnector() {
}
```

}

Comment: Did you check the mariadb java client jar is part of your WAR lib folder and when are you invoking this get connection method? Please share full exception stacktrace

Comment: Your comment was useful. There was problem nearby maven war plugin configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in maven war plugin configuration and webapp folder location.